# React build with webpack how to keep my config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, webpack, production-environment

I created a folder named 'config' in my React/Redux app where I put:

- config.development.json : contain a few variables used in the code
- config.production.json  : contain a few variables used in the code
- config.js  : Choose which config to load depending on the environment

When I run `npm run build` it generates a build folder, but it merges my config in the big JavaScript file.

What can I do to keep my config editable in the production build and separate from the main compile js?

I just don't want the customer to rebuild the project every time they want to change a variable value.

I have Webpack 2.6.1

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to be able to load that separate config file in a browser environment if it isn't bundled? Only method I can think of would be to not include it at all and utilise `window`, but that's less than ideal.

Comment: whats you mean by using ``window`` ? I just don't want the customer to rebuild the project every time he wants to change a variable value

Comment: I mean you could store the config object in the global/window object.

Comment: true that might be a way to solve the problem! I'll try that thanks